# All my products are known as "Invalid Product Identifiers"

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to create a third version of an application that is already on AppStore. I want to add products to buy by In App Purchase.

I've tried all that i've readen in the forum but without success, all my products are "Invalid Product Indentifiers".

- In my code, my products id are good.
- Provisionning Profile has been regenerated after products creation and application built with it
- I've disconnected my device from iTunes
- The "Cleared for Sale" checkbox is checked
- I test with my iPhone and not on the simulator
- I test on debug mode from XCode
- My products are cretaed from a long time (few days) so they must be availables
- I've tried to submit the application and reject it.

I don't know how to resolve my problem. I need help. What can I test?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Answer (score 1):

You said you reissued the provisioning profile, but did you also enable In-App Purchase on the app ID in the provisioning portal?

Comment: It is not necessary anymore, isn't it? Otherwise, where can I find this option?

Comment: Ah, perhaps it is not.  It's been a while since I've set up in-app purchase.  It appears to be enabled automatically for apps that use a bundle identifier other than `*`.

Comment: Yes. It's my case. Have you an idea from where is the problem?

Comment: Have you logged out of the iTunes store on your device, and created a sandbox account in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 1):

This happens a lot to us for unknown reasons, I usually end up having to delete the app from the phone, log out of the store (using Settings app) and perhaps reboot the phone.

Then after reinstall & restart you should be fine.